# Decide grouporder

Tags: wpf, collectionview

I have a list with users that I'm grouping by status (online, offline, etc..).
This is the enum class:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Enums
{
    public enum StatusEnum
    {
        [Description("Online")]
        Online = 1,

        [Description("Doorgeschakeld")]
        Forwarded = 2,

        [Description("In pauze")]
        Pauze = 3,

        [Description("Bezet")]
        Offline = 4,

        [Description("Slaapstand")]
        Sleeping = 5,

        [Description("Niet aangemeld")]
        NoStatus = 6,
    }
}
```

I'm trying to set to order of the groups in the list by setting it to an integer, but this does not work.

This is a screenshot of my application, as you can see the order is messed up:

[image]

This is my viewmodel class where I set the groupDescriptions on the CollectionView

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Data;
using LynxOneClient.Enums;
using LynxOneClient.Models;

namespace ViewModels
{
    public class AllUserViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<UserViewModel> UserList { get; set; }

        private List<UserViewModel> OnlineContacts { get; set; }

        private List<UserViewModel> LocalContacts { get; set; }

        public CollectionView UserView { get; private set; } 

        public AllUserViewModel()
        {
            UserList = new ObservableCollection<UserViewModel>();
            OnlineContacts = new List<UserViewModel>();
            LocalContacts = new List<UserViewModel>();

            UserView = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(UserList);

            // Filter
            if(UserView.CanFilter)
                UserView.Filter = OnFilterUsers;

            // Group
            if(UserView.CanGroup && UserView.GroupDescriptions != null)
                UserView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription(UserViewModel.StatusPropertyKey));
        }
    }    
}
```

And userViewModel class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using LynxOneClient.Enums;
using LynxOneClient.Models;

namespace LynxOneClient.ViewModel
{
    public class UserViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        #region Property keys
        public const string StatusPropertyKey = "Status";
        #endregion

        public UserViewModel()
        {
        }

        #region Properties

        public StatusEnum Status
        {
            get { return _user.StatusEnum; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _user.StatusEnum)
                    return;

                _user.StatusEnum = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(StatusPropertyKey);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is UserView defined? Is it a CollectionView? If it is, see remarks section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.sortdescriptions(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I add this

```
UserView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(UserViewModel.StatusPropertyKey, ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

The groups are sorted according to the integer that is given in the enum declaration.